# how to run junit tests on a examples file

Tags: java, input, configuration, junit

I have a method under test which gets as input 2 strings and returns a double.

Instead of writing a separate UT for each of them like this:

```
   public void test1() throws Exception {
        double answer = nameSimilarity.similarity("aaaa", "abbba");
        assertThat(answer, greaterThan(THRESHHOLD));
    }
```

I want to write a write an input batch file like this:

`string1 - string 2 - expect result to be greater than THRESHHOLD`

`aaaa -   abbba     - True`

`cccc -   abbba     - True`

`cccc -   zzzzz     - False`

how do you suggest I'll read the file, parse it and run a unit test on each row?

Is there any built in such functionality in junit with any convention ?

Comment: I think this should be possible with parameterized testing in JUnit.

Comment: can I change the delimiter? from `,` to `;` ?

Comment: Yeah, the idea with parameterized tests is that you build up a list of lists as the input to the tests. Each list is used to hold the arguments to provide for the particular test. So you could read the file and build up the list of lists for the tests. The format of the file could then be whatever you wanted it to be.

Comment: can you please show me how to change the git project `parameterized  JUnit` to work with `;` delimeter?

Comment: Check out this [documentation](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html) for the Paramterized test runner. In the `data()` method you could read your file for the inputs and then build up the list of lists data structure (actually a Collection of Object arrays in the example)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look behaviour driven development [cucumber](http://cukes.info/), which can support such kind of testing sample data called "[Data Tables](http://cukes.info/step-definitions.html)".

For example:

```
Scenario Outline: Email confirmation
  Given I have a user account with my name "Jojo Binks"
  When an Admin grants me <Role> rights
  Then I should receive an email with the body:
    """
    Dear Jojo Binks,
    You have been granted <Role> rights.  You are <details>. Please be responsible.
    -The Admins
    """
  Examples:
    |  Role     | details                                         |
    |  Manager  | now able to manage your employee accounts       |
    |  Admin    | able to manage any user account on the system   |
```

Comment: can i use file instead? not BDD ?

Comment: yes, you can just read the file and *assert* each line.You don't have to write a separate UT method for each for them.

Answer (score 0):

there is no such functionality in junit. also, in Junit you normally run each test case separately and give each a different name. Junit discourages running many tests in the same test case (it will fail if only one out of 20 tests succeed or 19 of them fail).
Your test case should have the general structure of:

```
public void testTooManyCases() {
   while get a line and !eof // catch exceptions and in finally close the file
      parse the line 
      //e.g:  String[] parts = line.split(","); //use comma to separate in the input file

      //calculate the answer for the info in the line
      //e.g: double answer = nameSimilarity.similarity(parts[0], parts[1]);

      //assert
      //e.g.: assertTrue((answer > THRESHHOLD) == new Boolean(parts[2]).booleanValue());
}
```

your file should have in each line something like:
aaaa,abbba,true
cccc,zzzzz,false